# Why the sqlite db is encrypted after i start a transaction?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite.swift

I'm using this code to start a transaction in my actual bd:

```
let stmt = try db.prepare("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
try stmt.run()
```

But after i close the transaction and want to check the db, i can't open it because it's encrypted, and i need a key, but i never declared one.
Thanks

Comment: if you run it in a block ([see docs](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#transactions-and-savepoints)) does it still cause the encrypted db?

Comment: What i did was to make function to open and close the transaction, i make a lot of inserts to the db, so i really can't make a block out of those operations.

Comment: what error do you get, precisely (code, message), and when (on which action)?

Comment: it appears that the error was from the sqlite viewer that i was using, i used another and it all went fine, i don't know why it said that was encrypted, anyway, thanks guys